# How to create delegate with partially predefined arguments?

Tags: c#, delegates

Let's say I have a delegate declaration taking one int as argument:

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(int i);
private MyDelegate _myDelegate = null;
```

and I have some function that takes a string and an int as arguments

```
private MyFunc(string s, int i){
    ...
}
```

Now I'd like to create a MyDelegate from MyFunc by specifying the string argument already in advance but leaving the int argument open. something like:

```
_myDelegate = new MyDelegate(MyFunc("Hello", ?));
```

whereas the ? would mark the still open argument that would need to be passed when invoking _myDelegate. I know this is is possible in other languages (for example, the ? syntax is comming from Eiffel agents).

how to do this in C#?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 6):

You can use a [lambda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx). Since the type can be inferred, you don't need to explicitly say `new MyDelegate(...)`.

```
_myDelegate = i => MyFunc("Hello", i);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a lambda expression to achieve this kind of partial-function application:

```
_myDelegate = new MyDelegate(i => MyFunc("Hello", i));
```

Since `_myDelegate` is of type `MyDelegate`, you can also assign it the lambda directly:

```
_myDelegate = i => MyFunc("Hello", i);
```